# How can I add a percent increase on the original price?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

return the new price of the item which is `80%` of the current unit price. This new field should be named `New_Price` while the original `unit_price` field should be names `old_price`.

Table is `ITEMS` which consists of `ITEM_ID, TITLE, ARTIST, UNIT_PRICE`

Comment: Requirements-only questions do not get much attention on Stack Overflow.  Please include some table data, and any query with which you might be currently stuck.

Comment: Adding input data and the expected data would be very helpful.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question to fit those guidelines. It will make it way easier to answer your question, and you will have a bigger chance at getting the answer(s) you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you want to create a new column in your table, or you just want to query the table.

**New column**

Assuming the price column type is `DECIMAL(10,2)`, let's have a look of the steps. If the data type is different, you just change it according to your column settings.

Rename the old column

```
ALTER TABLE items CHANGE COLUMN unit_price old_price DECIMAL(10,2) NULL;
```

Create the new column

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD COLUMN unit_price DECIMAL(10,2) NULL AFTER old_price;
```

Finally, you need to populate the values

```
UPDATE items SET unit_price = old_price * 0.8;
```

**Query (no new column)**

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  title,
  artist,
  unit_price AS old_price,
  unit_price * 0.8 AS unit_price
FROM items;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you specify the table structure, sample input and and expected output.

Based on what is mentioned, you can use triggers for that. For each entry in the table, the MYSQL server will fire a query according to the condition specified. Your query should look something like this

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER trig_unitPrice AFTER INSERT ON ITEMS
   FOR EACH ROW SET New_Price= NEW.unit_Price * 0.8;
```